# Unrelated entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I have a list of notifications...

```
IList<notification> notifications = db.notification.ToList();
```

Each of those notifications has a business id that correlates to a business entity, but there is no FK relationship.

I need to display the notifications along with the business name of each...

- notification 1 business a
- notification 2 business a
- notification 3 business a
- notification 4 business b
- notification 5 business c

I have done something similar with a viewmodel

```
public person person {get; set;}
public IList<notification> notifications {get; set;}
```

But I was able to fill the notifications in the viewmodel becuase I had a single person id, with which I could grab notifications that had that personid.

In this case, I don't have a single notificationid to grab businesses becuase its a list of notifications...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your 2 lists. I have scratched this together in linqpad on the fly. It will most likely not represent your models 1 to 1, so you need to adapt it. Since you have a notificartion list, I assumed you also have a business-list and created a similar model. The most important part is:

```
//nList = List of Notifications | bList = List of businesses
var JoinedBusiness = from not in nList
                     join busi in bList
                     on not.BusinessId equals busi.Id 
                     select new { Notification = not.Name, Business = busi.Name };
```

You may want to create a ViewModel out of it, if you need a strongly typed entity instead of an anonymous object.

Here's the complete code so you an reproduce it (just paste it into linqpad):

```
void Main()
{
    List<Business> bList = new List<Business>()
    {
        new Business(1, "Business1"),
        new Business(2, "Business2"),
        new Business(3, "Business3"),
        new Business(4, "Business4"),
        new Business(5, "Business5"),
    };

    var nList = new List<Notification>()
    {
      new Notification(1, "Notification1", 1),
      new Notification(2, "Notification2", 1),
      new Notification(3, "Notification3", 3),
      new Notification(4, "Notification4", 2),
      new Notification(5, "Notification5", 2),
      new Notification(6, "Notification6", 2),
    };

    var JoinedBusiness = from not in nList
                         join busi in bList
                         on not.BusinessId equals busi.Id 
                         select new { Notification = not.Name, Business = busi.Name };

    JoinedBusiness.Dump();

}
public class Notification
{
    public Notification(int id, string name, int businessid)
    {
     this.Id = id; this.Name = name; this.BusinessId = businessid;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
}

public class Business
{
    public Business(int id, string name)
    {
      this.Id = id;
      this.Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

//edit: if you need it strongly typed, you will need a viewmodel:

```
public class BusiNotVM
{
    public Notification Notifications { get; set; }
    public Business Businesss { get; set; }
}
```

alter your query to return the new ViewModel:

```
var JoinedBusiness = from not in nList
                     join busi in bList
                     on not.BusinessId equals busi.Id 
                     select  new BusiNotVM 
                     { 
                       Businesss = busi,
                       Notifications = not
                     };
```

This gives you the following output:
Every horizontal line represents entites which are joined; read: the IDs match. Just iterate over them in your view with `model.Business.Name` or `model.Notifications.Name`
Remember, also to change the model which your  view expects to your viewmodel:
`@model Namespace.Folder.BusiNotVM` - Have fun.

[image]

Comment: how would I make this available in my view? Its an anonymous type, and I'd like it to be strongly typed if possible.